# PIP warning when installing speedtest-cli

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, pip

I'm trying to install speedtest-cli in Linux with PIP but it keeps showing this warning message:

```
WARNING: The scripts speedtest and speedtest-cli are installed in '/home/rafik/.local/bin'      which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The second line says "if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location". Or, the first line indicates that directory is not on your `$PATH` - you can just add that to your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message really says it all - you need to add that directory to your `$PATH` variable. E.g.:

```sh
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/rafik/.local/bin
```

It's probably a good idea to add such a statement to some file that's loaded when you open a new shell (such as `.bashrc` if you're using bash).